# Mingw doesn't compile due to "'isblank' was not declared in this scope" error

Tags: c++, c++11, mingw

I try to compile & link the following program with mingw. When I use the default version it works well. But when I use c++11 version it doesn't compile and gives me the following error `newfile.cpp:22:18: error: 'isblank' was not declared in this scope`.
for testing the following program it's enough to call the `_isblank` function in main.

For compiling the Netbeans 8.0.2 uses `g++    -c -g -Wall -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/newfile.o.d" -o build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/newfile.o newfile.cpp`.

The mingw version is 4.8.1 and everything is configured well(Default).

I tried by adding/removing namespace std. The problem seems to be in cctype header! But I wonder how to solve it. The project will have to be compiled with g++ on linux! Will these problems remain?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cctype>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <functional>
#include "newfile.h"

using namespace std;
conf_info_t CONF_INFO;

#define CONF_FILE_ADDRESS "confs.txt"
//
//typedef std::map<std::string, std::function<void (const std::string&)>> confMap_t;
//confMap_t confMap;

int _isblank(int c){
    return isblank(c);
    //return c == ' ' || c == '\t';
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to recursively call _isblank?

Comment: sure! I wrote _isblank because isblank didn't work anywhere in the program with std=c++11 but I can't reinvent all the library functions because they are not found by compiler!

Comment: Generally functions beginning with underscore are reserved for compilers or library implementations. Have you tried grepping the MinGW include headers for isblank?

Comment: I tried also with istDasBlank() but there is no difference

Answer (score 2):

In my version of GNU library the declaration of `isblank` in `<ctype.h>` header is protected by some conditional compilation directives, which nevertheless should make this function available in C++.

However, in `<cctype>` header this function is is separated from all other declarations and given a special treatment for some reason. It is only made available in namespace `std` if macro `_GLIBCXX_USE_C99_CTYPE_TR1` is defined. This is what it looks like inside `<cctype>`

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L

#ifdef _GLIBCXX_USE_C99_CTYPE_TR1

#undef isblank

namespace std
{
  using ::isblank;
} // namespace std

#endif // _GLIBCXX_USE_C99_CTYPE_TR1

#endif // C++11
```

I don't know what the purpose that `_GLIBCXX_USE_C99_CTYPE_TR1` macro is supposed to serve. In my GCC installation this macro is defined, which makes `isblank` available in my case.

You might want to check what your `<cctype>` looks like and see if something like that is happening on your side as well.

Answer (score 1):

It worked when I undefined **STRICT_ANSI** in the translation unit adding -U__STRICT_ANSI__ to the compiler options. But I wonder which part of my program violates C++ standards.

It should have been compiled in this way:

```
g++ -U__STRICT_ANSI__   -c -g -Wall -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/main.o main.cpp
```

Comment: Other than the leading underscore(which you said you had changed), everything looks okay. What does your .h look like? Just the function prototype?

Comment: The header only defines conf_info_t and nothing else!